# Heroku error code h10 when trying to deploy react app

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Hin im kinda new to web development. I built a react website but i can't manage to deploy it on heroku.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
    },
```

I have a Procfile next to my package.json with :

```
web:npm start
```

console throw this error when i do herolu logs --tail :

```
2020-04-25T09:16:16.142345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vertikalreunion.herokuapp.com request_id=f7d41b53-de86-4b4d-83fb-994cab236581 fwd="82.64.226.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-25T09:16:27.595683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-25T09:16:51.753401+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T09:16:51.753423+00:00 app[web.1]: > vertikal@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-25T09:16:51.753423+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-25T09:16:51.753423+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T09:16:54.009357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-25T09:16:53.900786+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.53.194/
2020-04-25T09:16:53.901127+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-25T09:16:53.901196+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-25T09:16:53.901262+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-25T09:16:53.901440+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-25T09:16:53.901458+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T09:16:55.709712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vertikalreunion.herokuapp.com request_id=09ca158b-97f3-4693-9393-cd06adf078f5 fwd="82.64.226.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-25T09:19:08.785514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-25T09:19:30.469551+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T09:19:30.469601+00:00 app[web.1]: > vertikal@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-25T09:19:30.469602+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-25T09:19:30.469602+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T09:19:32.893506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-25T09:19:32.802075+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.5.2/
2020-04-25T09:19:32.802231+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-25T09:19:32.802333+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-25T09:19:32.802403+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-25T09:19:32.802595+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-25T09:19:32.802596+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T09:41:17.364623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-25T09:41:38.385042+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T09:41:38.385060+00:00 app[web.1]: > vertikal@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-25T09:41:38.385061+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-25T09:41:38.385061+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T09:41:40.279176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-25T09:41:40.184921+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.183.158/
2020-04-25T09:41:40.185258+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-25T09:41:40.185335+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-25T09:41:40.185406+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-25T09:41:40.185581+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-25T09:41:40.185582+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T10:23:03.438472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-25T10:23:25.751986+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T10:23:25.752002+00:00 app[web.1]: > vertikal@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-25T10:23:25.752002+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-25T10:23:25.752002+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T10:23:28.152557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-25T10:23:28.051089+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.19.226/
2020-04-25T10:23:28.051680+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-25T10:23:28.051715+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-25T10:23:28.051831+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-25T10:23:28.052068+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-25T10:23:28.052068+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T11:42:46.689638+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vertikalreunion.herokuapp.com request_id=5ca84f44-a006-4deb-a61b-b288a3a04109 fwd="82.64.226.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-25T11:43:34.646592+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `printenv` by user velluetp@gmail.com
2020-04-25T11:43:52.591042+00:00 heroku[run.1701]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-25T11:43:57.024009+00:00 heroku[run.1701]: State changed from up to complete
2020-04-25T11:46:45.991288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-25T11:47:07.851528+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T11:47:07.851557+00:00 app[web.1]: > vertikal@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-25T11:47:07.851558+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-25T11:47:07.851558+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T11:47:10.275055+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-25T11:47:10.153858+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.160.154/
2020-04-25T11:47:10.154471+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-25T11:47:10.154540+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-25T11:47:10.154659+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-25T11:47:10.154945+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-25T11:47:10.154946+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T12:01:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user velluetp@gmail.com
2020-04-25T12:01:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9c187c58-5551-4ceb-8b9b-bc3ef1e25101/activity/builds/69305220-a27f-436d-8841-9f17a17017e4
2020-04-25T12:11:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user velluetp@gmail.com
2020-04-25T12:13:26.032267+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d028d641 by user velluetp@gmail.com
2020-04-25T12:13:26.032267+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user velluetp@gmail.com
2020-04-25T12:13:27.646789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-25T12:13:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-25T12:13:48.056119+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T12:13:48.056133+00:00 app[web.1]: > vertikal@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-25T12:13:48.056133+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-25T12:13:48.056134+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T12:13:50.150679+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-25T12:13:50.228845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-25T12:13:50.028096+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.46.74/
2020-04-25T12:13:50.028436+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-25T12:13:50.028512+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-25T12:13:50.028579+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-25T12:13:50.028756+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-25T12:13:50.028757+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T12:14:16.995981+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T12:14:16.995997+00:00 app[web.1]: > vertikal@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-25T12:14:16.995997+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-25T12:14:16.995998+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T12:14:19.993371+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-25T12:14:19.866235+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.253.118/
2020-04-25T12:14:19.866644+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-25T12:14:19.866749+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-25T12:14:19.866883+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-25T12:14:19.867083+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-25T12:14:19.867084+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T12:14:22.011941+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vertikalreunion.herokuapp.com request_id=e69732b6-851b-46ca-9853-4a014a45f282 fwd="82.64.226.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-25T12:14:33.524773+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user velluetp@gmail.com
2020-04-25T12:14:54.113480+00:00 heroku[run.9122]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-25T12:14:58.860885+00:00 heroku[run.9122]: State changed from up to complete
```

I have no idea where the problems comes from, even after hard-trying to find solution on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

dont use to start scripts, remove "dev": "react-scripts start",

When using create-react-app and deploying to

1. dont delete the favicon.ico and manifest.json
2. also in package.json above scripts insert "engines": {
   "npm": "6.x",
   "node": "12.x"
   },

//NOTE CHECK YOUR NODE AND NPM VERSIONS BY TYPING npm -v and node -v for accurate versions//

3. In heroku after heroku create command, go to heroku and change buildback under settings to https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Dont add other scripts or change the start, build scripts!

This should clear all h10 errors when deploying to heroku, if they dont i suggest you create a new directory and copy your files there and start over, this link is a great guide to deploy

https://dev.to/smithmanny/deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-2b6f